# Why is there no password verification when changing passwords?

Tags: support, bug

My jimmies were somewhat rustled when I didn't get prompted for my current password when modifying it.

Comment: Holy hell, you're right! That's a pretty rooky mistake from them... I suppose they are hoping that random account GUID in the URL will prevent willy-nilly 3rd party password resets, but still... That's pretty bad.

Comment: Filed as a featreq in 2014: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232256/can-the-change-password-dialog-please-ask-for-my-current-password